# Scrapy instance method mysteriously refusing to call another instance method

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, control-flow

I'm using Scrapy to scrape a site that has a login page followed by a set of content pages with sequential integer IDs, pulled up as a URL parameter.  This has been successfully running for a while, but the other day I decided to move the code that yields the Requests into a separate method, so that I can call it other places besides the initial load (basically, to dynamically add some more pages to fetch).

And it... *just won't call* that separate method.  It reaches the point where I invoke `self.issue_requests()`, and proceeds right through it as if the instruction isn't there.

So this (part of the spider class definition, without the separate method) works:

```
    # ...final bit of start_requests():
    yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=LOGIN_URL + '/login', method='POST', formdata=LOGIN_PARAMS, callback=self.parse_login)

def parse_login(self, response):
    self.logger.debug("Logged in successfully!")
    global next_priority, input_reqno, REQUEST_RANGE, badreqs

    # go through our desired page numbers
    while len(REQUEST_RANGE) > 0:
        input_reqno = int(REQUEST_RANGE.pop(0))

        if input_reqno not in badreqs:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=REQUEST_BASE_URL + str(input_reqno), method='GET', meta={'input_reqno': input_reqno,'dont_retry': True}, callback=self.parse_page, priority = next_priority)
            next_priority -= 1

def parse_page(self, response):
    # ...
```

...however, this slight refactor does not:

```
    # ...final bit of start_requests():
    yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=LOGIN_URL + '/login', method='POST', formdata=LOGIN_PARAMS, callback=self.parse_login)

def issue_requests(self):
    self.logger.debug("Inside issue_requests()!")
    global next_priority, input_reqno, REQUEST_RANGE, badreqs

    # go through our desired page numbers
    while len(REQUEST_RANGE) > 0:
        input_reqno = int(REQUEST_RANGE.pop(0))

        if input_reqno not in badreqs:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=REQUEST_BASE_URL + str(input_reqno), method='GET', meta={'input_reqno': input_reqno,'dont_retry': True}, callback=self.parse_page, priority = next_priority)
            next_priority -= 1
    return

def parse_login(self, response):
    self.logger.debug("Logged in successfully!")
    self.issue_requests()

def parse_page(self, response):
    # ...
```

Looking at the logs, it reaches the "logged in successfully!" part, but then *never* gets "inside issue_requests()", and because there are no scrapy Request objects yielded by the generator, its next step is to close the spider, having done nothing.

I've never seen a situation where an object instance just refuses to call a method.  You'd expect there to be some failure message if it can't pass control to the method, or if there's (say) a problem with the variable scoping in the method.  But for it to silently move on and pretend I never told it to go to `issue_requests()` is, to me, bizarre.  Help!

(this is Python 2.7.18, btw)

Comment: `issue_requests()` is a *generator* - merely calling it does not execute any of the code inside, you have to iterate over its return value to do that.

Comment: it's inside a `while` loop such that each call should generate a bunch of requests, just the same as the loop does when it's part of `parse_login()`, no?  When run in the "pre" example, it empties REQUEST_RANGE, which could have thousands of entries, and generates a Request for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to yield items from `parse_login` as well:

```py
def parse_login(self, response):
    self.logger.debug("Logged in successfully!")
    for req in self.issue_requests():
        yield req
```